# Cannot bind store on Ext.form.field.Text - missing a setStore method

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

i am new to extjs and i am new to stackoverflow my viewModel and all stores is just perfect bind and still this error appears i dont know how to fix this please someone help me 
[these are the errors which appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoNz7.png)

Comment: Exactly what it says. How would you bind a store to a text field? A store is a collection of records. A record is a collection of fields. It's like saying "how do I bind a database table to a text field".

Comment: thank you very much.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Sir, I already have it. I was just binding a store to textfield instead of combobox.

```js
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  anchor: '100%',
  fieldLabel: 'Ssahjask',
  labelWidth: 130,
  name: 'asdhaskfja',
  valueField: 'id',
  bind: 
  {
    store: '{asdasdkasd}'
  }
},
```